# RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded while using graphicsmagick (npm gm) in SailsJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js, callstack, graphicsmagick

I'm facing a weird issue when I try to convert a TIFF file to JPG in the server using graphicsmagick ([npm gm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gm)). When I try to use any method of gm package, I am getting the RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded.

```
getInvoiceImage: function(req, response) {
    var gm = require('gm');
    var id = req.param('doc');
    console.log('----Logging from getInvoiceImage -----');
    console.log('id is :', id);
    gm('/opt/AppName/assets/images/downloads/fileName.tiff').identify( function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        pageCount = data.Iterations.length;
        console.log('Page count is :', pageCount);
        response.status(200).send({'pageCount':pageCount});
    });
},
```

When I create a test file in the server and use the pseudo-code, and run using "node test.js", it works.

```
var getImage = function() {
    var gm = require('gm');
    gm('/opt/AppName/assets/images/downloads/fileName.tiff').identify( function(err, data) {
        if(err) throw err;
        pageCount = data.Iterations.length;
        console.log('Page count is :', pageCount);
    });
}

getImage();
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try any npm another packages. alternatives gm

Comment: Could you please suggest any better packages for converting a TIFF file containing multi-pages to JPG?